# how to set up GTk 2 in codeblock

Tags: c, gtk, codeblocks

I want to setup gtk2 and i did:

```
compiler option:pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
likker option:pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0
```

I added the path gtk2 to variable path and add gdk-pixbuff to a user variable
but when i compile the code below;

```html
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *vbox;

  GtkWidget *menubar;
  GtkWidget *filemenu;
  GtkWidget *file;
  GtkWidget *quit;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 200);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "menu");

  vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
  filemenu = gtk_menu_new();

  file = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("File");
  quit = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");

  gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(file), filemenu);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(filemenu), quit);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), file);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 3);

  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quit), "activate",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

errors is not defined refrence

**Error Log:**

> ||=== gfffnewaa, Debug ===| obj\Debug\main.o||In function main':|
>       F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|15|undefined reference togtk_init_abi_check'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|17|undefined
>   reference to gtk_window_new'|
>       F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|18|undefined reference togtk_window_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|18|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'|
>       F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|18|undefined reference togtk_window_set_position'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|19|undefined
>   reference to gtk_window_get_type'|
>       F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|19|undefined reference tog_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|19|undefined
>   reference to gtk_window_set_default_size'|
>       F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|20|undefined reference togtk_window_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|20|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'

I am very upset and confused? How do I solve this problem?

> errors is not defined refrence
>
> ||=== gfffnewaa, Debug ===| obj\Debug\main.o||In function main':|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|15|undefined
>   reference togtk_init_abi_check'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|17|undefined
>   reference to gtk_window_new'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|18|undefined
>   reference togtk_window_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|18|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|18|undefined
>   reference togtk_window_set_position'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|19|undefined
>   reference to gtk_window_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|19|undefined
>   reference tog_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|19|undefined
>   reference to gtk_window_set_default_size'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|20|undefined
>   reference togtk_window_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|20|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|20|undefined
>   reference togtk_window_set_title'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|22|undefined
>   reference to gtk_vbox_new'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|23|undefined
>   reference togtk_container_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|23|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|23|undefined
>   reference togtk_container_add'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|25|undefined
>   reference to gtk_menu_bar_new'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|26|undefined
>   reference togtk_menu_new'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|28|undefined
>   reference to gtk_menu_item_new_with_label'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|29|undefined
>   reference togtk_menu_item_new_with_label'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|31|undefined
>   reference to gtk_menu_item_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|31|undefined
>   reference tog_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|31|undefined
>   reference to gtk_menu_item_set_submenu'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|32|undefined
>   reference togtk_menu_shell_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|32|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|32|undefined
>   reference togtk_menu_shell_append'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|33|undefined
>   reference to gtk_menu_shell_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|33|undefined
>   reference tog_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|33|undefined
>   reference to gtk_menu_shell_append'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|34|undefined
>   reference togtk_box_get_type'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|34|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|34|undefined
>   reference togtk_box_pack_start'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|36|undefined
>   reference to g_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|36|undefined
>   reference togtk_main_quit'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|36|undefined
>   reference to g_signal_connect_data'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|39|undefined
>   reference tog_type_check_instance_cast'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|39|undefined
>   reference to gtk_main_quit'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|39|undefined
>   reference tog_signal_connect_data'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|42|undefined
>   reference to gtk_widget_show_all'|
>   F:\Users\ROOT\Documents\codeblock\gfffnewaa\main.c|44|undefined
>   reference togtk_main'| ||=== Build finished: 39 errors, 0 warnings (0
>   minutes, 1 seconds) ===|

Comment: Have you tried "pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was that i used  **gtk x64** ,but codeblock work with **gtk x86**

now i use **gtkx86 and codeblock x86** it works nice.
some times there is now errors,only we is confused...

Comment: Please consider elaborating your response for future programmers with the same issue. [answer]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10838555)

Answer (score 0):

To compile a GTK+ application, you need to tell the compiler where to find the GTK+ header files and libraries. This is done with the pkg-config utility.

for header file you need to add below build option in codeblock option.

```
 pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

[image]

for library you need to add below build option in codeblock option.

```
 pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

[image]

Please go through it would help you.

Comment: i set this option,i talk that i do this in my comment,dont work code block??